# Dividing a polygon into two OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, polygon, splitting

I'm using OpenLayers to draw a polygon to my users. I want the ability to implement through a line, split the polygon into two, with the cutoff line that the user drew.

Does anyone know if this is possible to do with OpenLayers? Maybe indicate some link or sample stuff?

Comment: This is propably for you http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/Split-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.Split.OpenLayers.Control.Split